# Laravel auth to check for column before logging in

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and its built in Auth API. I've added a column to the `users` table called `is_admin`. I want to modify the login process so that login only works if `is_admin == 1`. I've looked in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php` ([Github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php)) and I could probably make a change there but I'd rather not disturb the core if possible. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Override the function in your own class that implements AuthenitacesUsers.

Comment: You could probably make a middleware for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this with a solution similar to @Sagar Arora's. In the `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php` that is created when you run `artisan make:auth`, I overrode the `attemptLogin` method from `AuthenticatesUsers`. This is the code in `LoginController.php`:

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return (auth()->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'is_admin' => 1]));
}
```

Now only users with `is_admin == 1` will be logged in.

Answer (score 3):

Just like you mentioned, you should never touch the core file. But if you could see laravel has added the `AuthenticatesUsers` as `trait` on LoginController which means you can simply **override** it by adding the `credentials()` in LoginController like the following.

```
/**
 * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return [
        'email'    => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => $request->input('password'),
        'is_admin' => 1
    ];
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I wonder whether that's preferable to my answer (overriding `attemptLogin` in `LoginController`).

Answer (score 2):

This solution may not be elegant, but still working.

Add this to `LoginController`:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ( ! $user->is_admin ) {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('login')->withErrors(['is_admin' => 'Only admin users may log in']);
    }
}
```

Then put this in `auth/login.blade.php`:

```
@if($errors->has('is_admin'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{ $errors->first('is_admin') }}</div>
@endif
```

Also keep in mind, that you should disable register functionality, because after registering a user still logs in.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your login function as:

So in your login function you can check this by:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'is_admin' => 1])) {
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

You check here manual login process with additional fields:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way is to actually allow all users to login. And then limit access via `admin` middleware. This way you may apply this middleware to as many routes as you like.

Use it by wrapping necessary routes in

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function() {
    // auth protected routes
});
```

This way you create `app\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAdmin`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class RedirectIfNotAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = $request->user();

        if ( $user && $user->is_admin ) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Then in `app\Http\Kernel.php` you append it to `$routeMiddleware` property:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        // ... other middlewares
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAdmin::class
    ];
```

Comment: Thanks. You say you think this is better - why (just curious)? I mean why not create a new guard called "admin", for example.

Comment: @GluePear Ok yes, a guard also may solve this. But if using `admin` guard, then assuming using the same `session` driver you would need to create the whole `admins` table and model. I think keeping users in one table is good practice, so that as your application grows, you just add permissions/roles. So yes using guard is a solution. But in this case I would say it is rather bold then elegant.

Comment: @GluePear Well I would also add that sometimes having several users table is ok too. For example when you have let say backoffice site that is available for admins only. But thinking it still could be done within one table. It would be nice to hear other approaches

Comment: Yes the guard approach seems like a lot of work when I just want to add one little option to the existing set up. I solved it with my answer above. But it's not ideal. My issue with your approach is that I want users who are not admins to see the login failure message - i.e. I don't want to log them in at all. Appreciate the help though.

Comment: @GluePear please take a look at [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42415478/4990125). Fail message is included there

Comment: Thanks. So many different answers here now I don't want to mark any as correct! My answer seems the simplest but also not very elegant.